# How can i fetch urls sequentially?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, async-await, fetch

I have array that contain urls. Firstly I need to fetch first and second urls simultaneously and when one of this will be resolved, i will fetch next url. Repeat while all urls wont be fetched. How can i do this ?

Comment: post your code what you tried if you have any.

Comment: You'd Promise.race the first two, then a simple promise chain for the subsequent urls ... something like `a.slice.(2).reduce((p,u)=>p.then(r=>fn(u)),Promise.race(a.slice(0,2).map(u=>fn(u))));` where `a` is your array of urls and `fn` is a function that handles the fetching of the urls, returning a promise that resolves when the url is fetched

Comment: or in an `async` function you can do the above using `await` ... easier to read `const res1=await Promise.race(a.slice(0,2).map(u=>fn(u)));
for (let u of a.slice(2)) {
    let res=await fn(u);
}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't show any code, so I'll have to provide a generic example.  `fetch()` returns a promise.  If you want to run a loop sequentially waiting for the promise of each `fetch()` operation, then the simplest way to do that is with `async` and `await`:

```
async function someFunc(array) {
    for (let item of array) {
        let result = await fetch(/* pass arguments here using item */);
        // process result here
    }
    return someValue;    // this becomes the resolved value of the promise
                         // the async function returns
}

// usage
// all async functions return a promise
// use .then() on the promise to get the resolved value
someFunc(someArray).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @elabugaa - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.